# Where should I ask questions about R (statistic language/software)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Often I have questions about R - a statistical programming language or a statistic software. Where can I ask questions about the software or how to solve statistical problems especially with that software (e.g. "Which command do I need for histograms?")?

Answer (score 0):

If you've a statistics question that you want to solve with R then it might be on topic on [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) which has an [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag that's described thus:

> Use this tag for any *on-topic* question that (a) involves `R` either as a critical part of the question or expected answer (b) is not *just* about how to use `R`.

Check the [help centre](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for cross-validated to make sure your question is on topic.

If your question is "how do I use R" then that's probably too broad to be on-topic anywhere.